# The findBy dynamic finder is returning null records in a portlet

Tags: grails, portlet, dynamic-finders

The findBy dynamic finder is returning null records in a portlet.

Have anyone got  dynamic finders to work inside a portlet?

In the console I have:

def results = stp.Spriden.findByPidm(72464)
println results.firstname

Exception thrown

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'firstname' on null object
    at ConsoleScript10.run(ConsoleScript10:2)

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Please format your code property. And post source code of your domain class `Spriden`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Scott! Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
def results = stp.Spriden.findByPidm(72464)
```

Shouldn't it be like below? Assuming *Spriden* is your domain class.

```
def results = Spriden.findByPidm(72464)
```

Sample could would help debugging the issue.

Comment: Take a look at output of error it's from console script. In which case declaration of package is likely to be required. The question should what is a pidms data type is input 78624 valid should that be 78264L instead  does 78264 even exist.  How about null safe checking whether that is wrapping it around if (results) { or.. results?.FirstName. who am I to judge poor quality questions that if end users thought of all these it wouldn't be a question